# Find original sales information of MacBook by serial number

Tags: macbook-pro, price, serial-number

Is there any way to figure out where my MacBook was sold and what the price was, by serial number only?

I know how to get information from Apple based on a serial number, but they did not tell me where it was sold or how much it was sold for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to Max Ried's answer, several more sites share EveryMac.com's functionality, including the following:

- [PowerBookMedic](http://www.powerbookmedic.com/identify-mac-serial.php)
- [Apple Serial Number Info](http://www.appleserialnumberinfo.com/Desktop/index.php)
- http://www.chipmunk.nl/klantenservice/applemodel.html (English translation is on the site)
- [Apple support website](http://support.apple.com/specs/) (this is really a search for tech specs, and I think you've already mentioned it in your question,  but you can also search by serial numbers here)

Comment: The funny thing is, these all websites provide absolutely different production week number :) but it's not a big deal, the most important isssue: they all does not provide what was the final price (with taxes, discounts etc)

Comment: that's interesting. as for the final price, i think the closest you're going to get is the original retail price...but I'll update this if I find anything else

Comment: Do you know the source of this information?

Answer (score 1):

[EveryMac.com](http://www.everymac.com/) lists the original US retail price. You can look up the machines by model name, code and more identifiers: [click here](http://www.everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/)

Comment: What i would like to know is the final price. With fees, discount etc ... is it possible ? and where it was buyed